# RPC, RMI, .NET remoting, CORBA?

Tags: .net, remoting, rmi, rpc, corba

I wonder if there is any technology from the mentioned below differs from the others or they are the same?

RPC, RMI, .NET remoting, CORBA.

Many thanks.

Comment: Note that .NET Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF. It should not be used for new development.

Comment: Pretty vague question. Of course they're not all the same, otherwise there would only be one of them. What criteria are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

they're all *roughly* the same. They take a bit of data, expressed in various forms, package it up into a network buffer, send it across the network, and then un-package it into the same form of data.

The idea is that they abstract away any knowledge of network protocols, so you can code without caring to understand networks, sockets, etc, and making you more productive.

SOAP is also a form of RPC - takes data, packages it into XML, transmits it across the http protocol, then un-packages it.

Comment: Thanks alot, but if we want to exclude one of these technologies, which one we choose?

Comment: by which criteria would you exclude them? Is this your homework?

Answer (score 0):

RPC and RMI are frameworks that enable remote method invocation. They offer you enough help to make remote calls as if you were making local ones, and not worry about details of marshaling the arguments and results, transport etc.

[CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture#CORBA_Component_Model_.28CCM.29) is a more extensive framework, which, in addition, offers common facilities that you need when programming distributed systems, like notification, authentication, persistence, transaction processing, location services etc.

.NET remoting is another modern framework that offers similar facilities. Also see [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx), which is meant to replace .NET remoting.